# Making a duplicate Foreign Key in schema bad practice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

Here's a summary of my tables:

```
---------
user_info
---------
id

---------
post
---------
id
user_id(Foreign Key)

---------
review
---------
id
post_id(Foreign Key)
```

I have cases where I need fetch reviews by the `user_id`.
Right now, I find posts with `user_id(FK)` then find reviews with `post_id(FK)` that match `post.id`

I wanted to ask if it's a bad practice to make another user_id(FK) in `review`
table because it is redundant

Comment: If you need info about the user how posted review of the post of the other user you definetly must have `UserId` at `review` and it is not redudant.

Comment: Just to clarify, so even if I can know the writer of the review by joining with the `post ` table(since both are the same person), It is not redundant to add foreign key `user_id` in `review` table?

Answer (score 0):

In your example data, you don't have a `user_id` in the `reviews` table.

However, if you did, it would probably be the user of the *reviewer*, not the *post author*.

Hence, it is something entirely different, you probably should have the column, and it should have a proper foreign key reference.

Comment: Oh I guess I needed to add some explanation. my service's posts consist of multiple reviews combined into one post. so in my case, the author of the post is the same person as the author of the review